# AutoFill username and password in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, autofill, ios12

I implemented AutoFill for stored username and password suggestion successfully in iOS 11.
I have two text fields in my login view controller, one for email, one for password. The content types are defined as follows:

[image]
<sub>*email / username text field configuration*</sub>

[image]
<sub>*password text field configuration*</sub>

This used to work just fine in iOS 11, but after upgrading my development iPad to iOS 12, the app suggests emails for the username field and the following happens when editing the password field:

[image]

---

In my create account view controller, I have 3 text fields: email, password, repeat password. Their content modes are setup as follows:

- email → email address
- password → new password, rule: `minlength:8;`
- repeat password → new password, rule: `minlength:8;`

When editing the email address field, it properly suggests an email address. For the password and repeat password fields, however, it suggests stored passwords, instead of suggesting a new password.

---

### What I tried

- (illogically) flip the content mode setup, so the login password field is set to `new password` and the create account password fields are set to `password`

  - no success; in fact, no change of behavior at all
- set content mode to `none` for login and create account fields so AutoFill can try to handle it automatically

  - no success; in fact, no change of behavior at all

---

### Note

- AutoFill is properly setup on the server. The stored passwords being suggested in the create account fields prove that
- The functionality is still working on iOS 11 iPads
- When logging in with a new username, the app will ask the user to add this username and password to Keychain, even on iOS 12

---

Any idea what I need to change so that stored username & password suggestion works in iOS 12 again?

Thanks!

---

---

### Edit

As requested by @kralex below, here's my view hierarchy for the login view controller in the storyboard:

[image]

...and on the device:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is doing some heuristic to make the best guess what you might need: autofill or a new password. However in some cases it might fail.

In your case the problem is related to the "Create Account Button". It makes the system think that it is a sign up form.

The easiest option to fix it: replace sign up UIButton with UILabel and add tapRecognizer to handle taps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Funny thing is: I'm actually using a view that holds a label that is tapable instead of a button.

Comment: From the view hierarchy it looks like that sign up is actually a UIButton, but log in is a UIView with probably UILabel.

If log in is UILabel, that try to make it UIButton, it should fix the issue as well.

Comment: Ohh you mean the lower one. I see. I was talking about the login button, sorry. I'll try that out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This actually worked. On the one hand, it's cool that Apple is able to detect stuff like that. On the other hand, it's not so cool, because they put their heuristics over the manually assigned content types. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Can you tell me how I can have the text fields in the create account view controller suggest a new password? They don't suggest a stored username and password anymore, but don't suggest a new password either. I have tried to add a (hidden) button saying "Create Account" to trigger the algorithm, but that doesn't work...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer yet. I have the same problem so far.

Comment: What works for me right now is changing the text fields from `new password` to just `password`. Weird...

Comment: `new password` should be used when you let user change the old password. So it's definitely not for login or sign up.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and found out Apple's heuristics were tapping in to the *class name of the view controller* to determine whether to suggest a new password or use an existing one. It seems like even if I set the correct `textContentType` on my `UITextField`s, it still would use the name of the controller.

My `UIViewController` has both sign up and login on the same screen, but the controller is named `RegistrationViewController`. I changed it to `LoginViewController` to test, and found that the login portion started working, but the registration bit acted like it was login! Even with the correct `textContentType`s set!

I wound up having to rename my `UIViewController` something that doesn't imply registration or login for it to actually respect my `textContentType`s. It's awful. Truly awful.

I would imagine at least part of the reason this is/was happening to you is because the you have the word `Welcome` as the beginning of your view controller, unbelievable as it sounds.

By the way, I tried `RegistrationLoginViewController` (it chose the registration setup) and `LoginRegistrationViewController` (it chose the login setup), and neither worked. It has to avoid Apple's heuristics if you want to have both on the same controller.

Comment: Weird, my login view controller's class name was `LoginViewController`. Maybe the button name has a higher priority - which would make sense, as people often use a `LoginViewController` to let users login or signup, all in one vc and so the button's title should be weighed more.

Comment: Interesting catch, though! I feel like Apple should at least document those things. Plus, why do they even override the `contentType` settings...if it was not set at all, I get that, but when it's set??

Comment: Weird, my button was called `signInButton` and didn't seem to make any difference. I totally agree, this NEEDS documentation and a way to override whatever it is they're doing. Wild west out here lol.

Comment: Seriously Apple needs to stop thinking it knows what people want. A heuristic with no opt out? No thanks.